# Order rows in TableLayout

Tags: android, rows, tablelayout

I have TableLayout in my xml.

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/jobs_table"
             android:gravity="top"
             android:stretchColumns="*"
             android:shrinkColumns="*"/>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/monday"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/tuesday"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/wednesday"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/thursday"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/friday"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/saturday"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/sunday"/>
    </TableRow>
```

Then, I add rows with buttons in Activity.

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jobs);
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.jobs_table);
        // Make some buttons here.
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        tableLayout.addView(row, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

When I run application, row with TextViews from XML are on the bottom and Buttons from Java code are on the top. How can I reverse them(Buttons are on the button and row with TextViews are on the top)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did it as:

```
TextView[] days = new TextView[7];
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    days[i] = new TextView(context);
    days[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    row.addView(days[i]);
}
days[0].setText(R.string.monday);
days[1].setText(R.string.tuesday);
days[2].setText(R.string.wednesday);
days[3].setText(R.string.thursday);
days[4].setText(R.string.friday);
days[5].setText(R.string.saturday);
days[6].setText(R.string.sunday);
rowsWithButtons.add(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [this version of addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) does what you need (with index = 0)

> public void addView (View child, **int
>   index**)
>
> Adds a child view.
>   If no layout parameters are already
>   set on the child, the default
>   parameters for this ViewGroup are set
>   on the child. Parameters
>
> child the child view to add
>
> **index   the
>   position at which to add the child**

Comment: I tried it, but when I add row from Java code with index=0, it works the same, with index=1 it fails with Force close button.

Comment: Please attach she logcat dump so we can see why your app was closed, and please attach the exact code you used when it happened.

Comment: Dump [link](http://pastie.org/1659925) Process fails when it on string tableLayout.addView(row, 1, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));